# Avoiding InconsistentMigrationHistory with explicit inserts in migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a little problem with the order of the migrations. The fact is that in my database there is a "Products" model whose migration is one of the first in the history list, call it *001_products*. After this migration, others are executed that make inserts in this same table (some inserts necessary for the basic operation of the application), called migration *002_inserts_products*.

The problem appeared when modifying the "Products" model, call it *003_modify_products* migration. The migration was applied after the inserts and made the tests fail (tests that generate a test database doing all the migrations), which followed this order:

1. 001_products
2. 002_inserts_products
3. 003_modify_products

The solution then was to add a dependency on migrations that made inserts in "Products" with respect to the subsequent migration that modified that table. That is, make 002_inserts_products dependent on 003_modify_products.

However, this, which worked in the tests and locally (where the modification in "Products" had already been applied), does not work in production, since there the migration that has not been applied is the one that modifies the "Products" model ".

That is, the panorama in production is:

1. [X] 001_products
2. [X] 002_inserts_products
3. [ ] 003_modify_products

When trying to do the new migration, the error that appears is:

*django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration 002_inserts_products is applied before its dependency 003_modify_products on database 'default'.*

The question is how to set the migrations to work both in test and in production (that is, in the context that the previous migrations have already been done)?

Comment: Typically you don't need to change anything about migrations in production. It sounds like you've corrupted something somewhere. If your data isn't important to you, you can simply delete all migrations except for `init.py` & delete `db.sqlite3`. Then run `makemigrations` & `migrate` again and all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're trying to find a solution for a problem you created yourself by modifying an older migration to make it dependent on a newer migration to get around your tests failing.

The proper solution would be to do the following:

1. Remove `002_inserts_products`'s dependency on `003_modify_products`, and return it to its original state.
2. Add `004_update_products` to update any products inserted via `002_insert_products` so that they work with the table modifications in `003_modify_products`.
3. Update your tests to accommodate the changes made in `003_modify_products`.

It's never a good idea to change the expected ordering of migrations that have already run, because while it might work in your local environment, it's very likely to blow up when you're deploying to a server on which none of those migrations have run.

Also remember that tests failing is not always indicative of something you've done wrong -- tests, especially database tests, are not necessarily future-proof. It's totally normal to have to update tests due to schema changes.